# Making a leaderboard which resorts itself everytime someone plays

Tags: python, leaderboard

I am learning python coming from C++ and HTML, after studying I decided a good way to exercise was making a simple game then slowly developing. I made it this far, but got stuck on a few things: 1. storing the "player" class and its atributes in a txt file 2. adding the new players everytime someone else with a different name plays 3. sorting the list everytime someone new is added 4. displaying the list when a keyword is input from the keyboard ( split it in small steps as i always do when coding. )
Please help and explain the steps, here is the base code:

```
input('Welcome to rock, paper, scissors version 1.3!(contact me for updates) Press any key to continue.')
w = 0
l = 0
t = 0
class player:
    def __init__(self, name, wins, losses, ties):
        self.name = name
        self.wins = wins
        self.losses = losses
        self.ties = ties
def func1():
 global w, l, t
 x=input('Choose: rock, paper or scissors?')
 from numpy import random
 y = (random.randint(1, 3))
 if (x == "scissors") or (x == "rock") or (x == "paper"):
   if y == 1:
     y = "scissors"
   if y == 2:
     y = "rock"
   if y == 3:
     y = "paper"
 else: print("Error: you did not type your answer correctly: check so it is lowercase and spells the word correctly(as described in the question) and try again.")    
 if x == "rock" :
   if y == "paper" :
     print("computer chose " + y + " so you lost!")
     l = l + 1
   else:
     if y == "rock" :
           print("computer chose " + y + " so it is a tie!")
           t = t + 1
     else:
         print("computer chose " + y + " so you win!")
         w = w + 1
 if x == "paper" :
   if y == "scissors" :
     print("computer chose " + y + " so you lost!")
     l = l + 1
   else:
     if y=="paper" :
           print("computer chose " + y + " so it is a tie!")
           t = t + 1
     else:
         print("computer chose " + y + " so you win!")
         w = w + 1
 if x == "scissors" :
   if y == "rock" :
     print("computer chose " + y + " so you lost!")
     l = l + 1
   else:
     if y == "scissors" :
           print("computer chose " + y + " so it is a tie!")
           t = t + 1
     else:
         print("computer chose " + y + " so you win!")
         w = w + 1
 n=input('Play again?(y/n)')
 if n == "y":
   n = 0
   func1()
 if n == "n":
  print("You won " + str(w) + " times, lost " + str(l) + " times and it was a tie " + str(t) + " times.")
  p1 = player(input("Please type your name:"),w,l,t)
  input('Thanks for playing! Press any key to exit.')     
func1()
```